# To find whether a column exists in data frame or not

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with the name "abcframe"

```
     a  b  c
     1  1  1
     2  2  3
```

How might I find whether a column exists or not in a given data frame?
For example, I would like to find whether a **column d** exists in the data.frame **abcframe**.

Comment: Do you want to know whether your data frame has a column with a name of `d`, or do you want to know whether a given vector `d` equals one of the columns of your data frame?

Comment: i want to knnow whether dataframe has a cloumn with name d or not

Comment: Wish you nice Sunny day with 100 votes! :-)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Assuming that the name of your data frame is `dat` and that your column name to check is `"d"`, you can use the `%in%` operator:

```
if("d" %in% colnames(dat))
{
  cat("Yep, it's in there!\n");
}
```

Comment: if you are looking the inverse, i.e. if the column is not there, just add `!` at the beginning: `if(!"d"%in% colnames(dat))`

Comment: Awesome answer. How do I extend this if I'd be looking for columns 'd' and 'e' and 'f'? Would that be: `if("d" & "e" & "f" %in% colnames(dat))
{
  cat("Yep, it's in there!\n");
}`. Thanks! -- Oh, I may have found the answer myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770912/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-a-matrix-or-data-frame.

Comment: all(c("d", "e", "f") %in% colnames(dat))

Answer (score 34):

You have a number of options, including using `%in%` and `grepl`:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=4:5)
dat
  a b c
1 1 2 4
2 2 3 5
```

To get the names of the columns:

```
names(dat)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Use `%in%` to check for membership:

```
"d" %in% names(dat)
[1] FALSE

Or use `grepl` to check for a match:

grepl("d", names(dat))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: To get the `grepl` a bit more precise, you could use `grepl("^d$",names(dat))`, to ensure that a column with name `dd` does not return `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for this, `colnames` didn't work for me but `names` did.

Comment: @Andrie is there a way to compare the columns to two large dataframes to see which column names are missing from the other column?

Answer (score 11):

You could use `any`:

```
> names(dat)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> any(names(dat) == 'b')
[1] TRUE
> any(names(dat) == 'B')
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also use `if(!is.null(abcframe$d))` to test whether `d` exists in `abcframe`.

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 2:3, c = 4:5)

if (!is.null(dat$d)) {
  print("d exists")
} else {
  print("d does not exist")
}
if (!is.null(dat$a)) {
  print("a exists")
} else {
  print("a does not exist")
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this fails with the tidyverse tibble, because the 'dat$d' will throw a warning.

Comment: A warning is not an error, so it still works with a tibble

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse approach might be more readable for some people, and therefore better to remember.

You would search for the variable by `str_detect` which returns a logical vector like `grepl`, and then collapse this by the base R function `any` which returns TRUE if there was at least one TRUE value.

```
dat %>% names %>% str_detect("d") %>% any()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to specifically check for one column, a non-conventional way to do that would be to use `exists`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2),
  b = c(1,2),
  c = c(1,3)
)

exists("a", where = dat) # TRUE
exists("b", where = dat) # TRUE
exists("c", where = dat) # TRUE
exists("d", where = dat) # FALSE

# Does not work with multiple entries though
exists(c("a","b","c","d"), where = dat)
```

While `exists` is primarily used to check for variables in environments, it can also be used with data frames and lists because they can store named objects.