# How to check if a column exists in a matrix or data frame?

Tags: r

Is there a way to check if a column exist in a matrix or data.frame?

For example: TableA

```
Name    Age    Address     Contact No.
Ben     12     CA           1234567
```

How can I check if a column "Gender" or "Age" exist before I process a row?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `?grep` or `?grepl`, e.g. `grepl('^gender$|^age$', colnames(TableA))`, or `?'%in%'.

Comment: Uh, where is your `Gender` column?

Comment: @buruzaemon - it doesn't exist - I guess that is the point of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you realise that  columns `"Gender"` or `"Age"` either *do* or *don't* exist **for all rows** in the data frame?

An easy way to check is to take the names of the data frame and compare the columns you are inetrested with the names to see if they are included in that set. For example, some data as per your question:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = "Ben", Age = 12, Address = "CA", ContactNo = 1234567)
```

Note the `names` attribute for the data frame `df`:

```
names(df)

> names(df)
[1] "Name"      "Age"       "Address"   "ContactNo"
```

Then you can check to see if the variables of interest are in the set of variables in the data frame:

```
c("Gender", "Age") %in% names(df)

> c("Gender", "Age") %in% names(df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

For a matrix, you need the `colnames` attribute, accessed via the `colnames()` extractor function, instead of the `names` attribute and `names()`.

Comment: Looking `%in%` `colnames(df)` would be the general answer that works on both a `matrix` and `data.frame` object. You could also wrap the answer like `any(...)` to check if either of them exist.

Comment: Thank you Gavin and thelatemail for the answers and comments. Save me lots of time researching. I am really new to R. ^_^

Comment: @thelatemail that is a good point, but data frames don't have a `colnames` attribute, just a method that extracts the names. I personally prefer to use `names` on data frames as that is what I use on lists, hence I see the link between those two objects whereas `colnames()` sees a similarity between matrices and data frames. Each to their own :-) +1 for `any()`.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson Monica - G. Simpson is there a way to compare the colnames for two dataframes to see which are missing from the other dataframe?

Comment: @sar Try `?setdiff` and `?intersect` as in: `setdiff( names(data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C = 1:3)), names(data.frame(A = 1:3, C = 1:3)) )` and `intersect( names(data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C = 1:3)), names(data.frame(A = 1:3, C = 1:3)) )` and there are versions od the same functions in the *dplyr* package too