# R dataframe column created, but 'exists' is false and 'get' fails

Tags: r, variables

Minimum reproducible example:

```
times <- 0:365
df <- data.frame(times)
for (i in 1:5){
  for(j in 3:6){
    scen_name=paste("Scen",j,i,sep="_")
    scen_out <- sample(times)
    df <- cbind(df, scen_out)
    colnames(df)[length(df)] <- scen_name
  }
}
# Get user input for which variable to view / graph

Selection <- "Scen_4_2"

get(paste0('df$',Selection)))
```

This fails to retrieve the data.

And `exists(paste0('df$',Selection)))` returns false - but I can retrieve it perfectly well with `df$Scen_4_2`.

Note that I need to reference the variable indirectly because the name is being generated - so [checking or directly referencing the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276092/to-find-whether-a-column-exists-in-data-frame-or-not) is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't do this directly, because I need to be able to loop through columns in a more complex dataframe; df$Var.1, df$Var.2, etc., and I would like to use get() to do so.

Comment: You can loop through the column names, and use `[[` to extract the values. E.g. `for(x in names(df)) { sum(df[[x]]) }`

Comment: Great, but that's not what I need to do - there are only specific columns I need.

Comment: See if the solutions in the linked post work in your case. Based on what I understand from your post, I see no reason here to use `get` or `exists`.

Comment: @zx8754 The other solutions, which don't use get or exists, are irrelevant, per the earlier comment which I left to clarify exactly this point, but which was obviously ignored when the question was closed.

Comment: Please provide example input data, example data processing, and expected output.

Comment: Comments were not ignored, I am trying to suggest a better way of doing it. If you can be more specific with your problem, we can give you more direct answer. Please clarify `" I need to reference the variable indirectly because the name is being generated "` with an example code and expected output.

Answer (score -1):

The problem, I now realize, is that a dataframe needs to be specified as an environment to check the columns, or the dataframe needs to be attached.

so:

`get(Selection, envir=as.environment(df))`

or (though it is generally frowned upon,) if attaching the data frame is acceptable:

```
attach(df)
get(Selection)
```

Comment: Attaching is discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067680/680068

Comment: Using `df[['times']]` would be even more direct. That syntax allows for variables as well `a <- "times"; df[["times"]]` or if you just want to know if it exists `"times" %in% names(df)`

Comment: @MrFlick - Sure, but it doesn't do what is needed, since the names are going to vary in the actual application.

Comment: @DavidManheim I don't under stand you comment. `df[[Selection]]` would return the same as `get(Selection, envir=as.environment(df))`. The `[[` operator can take character variables.