# Make R error out when accessing undefined columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-integrity

This site has lots of questions on how to fix an "undefined column" error.

I have the exact opposite question: how to make an "undefined column" error.

I frequently change variable names in my files.

This leads to the following error:

```
r$> df <- data.frame(gender=c(1,1,NA,0))
r$> sum(is.na(df$male))
[1] 0
```

when the correct result is 1.

I want R to print an error message if the column I'm trying to access is undefined.

Not to silently fail.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately R is rather too lenient when it comes to such matters. The `$` operator for data.frames is defined to allow accessing non-existent columns and to return `NULL` in that case.

There are alternative data.frame implementations which are a bit stricter. Notably, the `tbl_df` data structure used by the Tidyverse packages ‘tibble’, ‘dplyr’, etc. will at least show you a warning:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(gender = c(1, 1, NA, 0))
sum(is.na(df$male))
# [1] 0
# Warning message:
# Unknown or uninitialised column: `male`.
```

Alternatively, you can make this a hard error for data.frames by overriding `$` for data.frames:

```
registerS3method(
  '$', 'tbl_df',
  \(x, name) {
    stopifnot(name %in% colnames(x))
    NextMethod('$')
  }
)
```

However, note that this will *only* apply to plain `data.frame`, not to tibbles, since the latter also override `$`. There does not seem to be an option to make this a hard error for tibbles (short of making *all* warnings into errors); this might be a nice feature request for the package (alternatively, you can make the above code apply to tibbles by replacing `'data.frame'` with `'tbl_df`).

Comment: I will make sure all my dataframes are tibbles from now on, at least I get something. I also noticed that [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) behaves like built-in `data.frame` and don't error out. Using tibbles, is it possible to convert that warning into an error and stop execution?

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean

```
sum(is.na(df$gender))
```

because you did not have create the column "male". For the correct code the result for the column "gender" is 1.
Moreover, in writing code, "r$>" is not necessary.

Comment: There is no column called `male`. Consequently, OP wants R to signal an error.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, it’s common to prefix R code with a prompt to interleave input and output (although it’s usually best practice to use a widely-recognised prompt such as `> ` instead of a more niche prompt that some readers might not recognise as such).

Comment: There is no column called `male`. Consequently, I want R to signal an error.

Comment: I think the answer is relative if X is a column of dataframe. See 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276092/to-find-whether-a-column-exists-in-data-frame-or-not)